# Dont know how to connect AC-97, HDAUDIO, and USB connectors to motherboard

Tags: usb, desktop-computer, usb-2, computer-name

I will provide pictures so you guys can see, but basically I recently bought a new case for my pre-built Lenovo k330b. I can't find how I'm supposed to position the connectors. Please help me out with this weird situation. Do I need to get an entirely new motherboard? Is there any adapter I can buy? Any help is welcome. Thank you!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8g5xqt2pao6qea/IMG_20141029_213758477.jpg?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m74k52zkqcuzdgv/IMG_20141029_213606190.jpg?dl=0

Comment: You don't connect them.  Your motherboard does not have those headers besides the single USB2 header.  The other two can't be used.  You just plug it in.

Comment: @Ramhound So you're saying ignore the hdaudio and ac97 connectors? If I do that I wont have front audio outputs?

Comment: Yes; ignore them; Those only connect the case ports; the motherboards has its own audio ports; the OEM case didn't have these plugs so your fine; you can't use functionality that doesn't exist